# IOError (closed stream) in ruby while saving the image

Tags: jquery, ruby, ajax

> here im trying to save the image in mysql database using ajax but each
>   time getting fail to upload the image, please help me out solve this.

Controller.rb

```
def image_converter
        sub = TestimonialPicture.new
        decoded_file = Base64.decode64(params[:picdata]) unless params[:picdata].nil?
        if request.post?
          begin
            tmpfilename = "#{params[:id]}#{Time.now.to_i.to_s}"
            file = Tempfile.new([tmpfilename, '.jpg'])  
            file.binmode
            file.write decoded_file
            file.close
            sub.testimonialpic = file
            if sub.save
              sub.update_attributes(:testimonial_id => params[:tid])
              msg = "YOur image has been successfully uploaded"
            else
              msg = "Failed to create submission. Please try again"
            end
          ensure
            file.unlink
          end
          render :text=>msg
        end
      end
```

> the image which i have created im going to convert that one to canvas
>   and saving, by clicking save button two functions im doing, using that
>   controller im able to get the image but but unable to store to
>   database.
>
> view.html.erb

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var element = $("#bgcolor"); // global variable
    var getCanvas; // global variable

    $("#save_btn").on('click', function () {
         html2canvas(element, {
         onrendered: function (canvas) {
                $("#previewImage").append(canvas);
                getCanvas = canvas;
             }
         });
    });

    $("#btn-Convert-Html2Image").on('click', function () {
      $("#popDiv").hide();
      var picdata = getCanvas.toDataURL("image/png");
      var pic = picdata.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, ""); 
        var tid = $("#tid").val();
        $.ajax({ 
          url: "/businessdb/image_converter",
          type: "POST",
          data: {"pic" : pic, "tid" : tid},
          dataType: "json",
          success: function(data) {
            location.reload();
            alert("success");
          }
        });
    });
```

> each time im getting an error like IOError(closed stream)
>
> I need to save my picture into mysqldatabase by clicking save button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problematic lines are

```
file.close
sub.testimonialpic = file
```

When the `mysql2` tries to save an `IO` to a BLOB column, that `IO` must be open to read. You just explicitly closed that file (which is an IO) before it is saved.

The solution is

```
file.rewind
sub.testimonialpic = file
```

And close that file in the `ensure` block before it's `unlink`ed.

Comment: MissingRequiredValidatorError (Paperclip::Errors::MissingRequiredValidatorError): after adding that agian same error in the line

Comment: Show me your model class.

Comment: it works fine for me can u please tell me once i save the image the new window should get close using ajax method

Comment: i have written inside the ajax methos

Comment: $("#btn-Convert-Html2Image").on('click', function () {
      $("#popDiv").hide();
      var picdata = getCanvas.toDataURL("image/png");
      var pic = picdata.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, ""); 
        var tid = $("#tid").val();
        $.ajax({ 
          url: "/businessdb/image_converter",
          type: "POST",
          data: {"pic" : pic, "tid" : tid},
          dataType: "json",
          success: function(data) {
     window.open(window.location, '_self').close();
          }
        });
    });

Comment: this is not closing the window but saving the image

Comment: Your second error is not related to the first. I recall that `Paperclip` urges you either validate the extensions of the uploaded files, or validate their MIME types. If you really want to allow  the users to upload arbitrary files, you have to explicitly tell `Paperclip` to skip validations. I just forgot how to do this, but you can easily find the documentation on github.